# When using CSS zoom, query-ui slider is behaving wrongly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, uislider

I have scale applied to the main wrapper of my application :

```
transform-origin: center top 0px;
transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(2.21538);
```

I have a jquery slider which is not behaving as expected because of scaling.

- the slider handle is jumping away from the cursor when it is dragged
- when the slider is clicked, the handle jumps to a different position

Comment: This is jquery conflict. you need to check the jquery you have used.

Comment: Have used https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js and https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the jquery.ui.js library in my local files to make it work

```
_slide: function( event, index, newVal ) {
  //add below line as first line of this function

  newVal = newVal / scaleFactor;

  //jquery code goes here
}
```

if you are using minified version

```
_slide: function(e, t, n) {
  n = n / scaleFactor;
}
```

hare the scaleFactor is the scaling value, 2.21538 in your case.
scaleFactor variable must be available in global scope, otherwise will get error.

Comment: It worked like a charm :) But I am not able to drag the handle after a certain point. I guess the range has also shifted. Can you please tell how to fix that?